# My goal is to get the value of cType and cSize from the two methods but it keeps returning "nullnull"

Tags: java

````
public class Main
{
    static String clotheOrder[] = {"FB02", null, null, null, "TS03", "GS04", null, "PA03"};
    int clotheQuantity[] = {3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0};
    static String cType, cSize;

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= clotheOrder.length; x++) {
            
            if (clotheOrder[x] == null) {
                
                System.out.println("No order");
                continue;
            }
            else {
            System.out.println(clotheType(clotheOrder[x].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")) 
                               + clotheSize(clotheOrder[x].replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "")));
            }
        }
    }
    static String clotheType(String type) {
            
                 if (type == "FB" ) {cType = "Blouse .............";}
            else if (type == "TS" ) {cType = "T-Shirt ............";}
            else if (type == "GS" ) {cType = "Garterized Shorts ..";}
            else if (type == "PA" ) {cType = "Pants ..............";}
            else if (type == "PS" ) {cType = "Pencil Skirt .......";}
            else if (type == "CC" ) {cType = "Chinese Collar Polo ";}
            else if (type == "PW" ) {cType = "White Slacks .......";}
            else if (type == "RB" ) {cType = "Round Neck Blouse ..";}
            else if (type == "S"  ) {cType = "Skirt ..............";}
            else if (type == "VN" ) {cType = "V-Neck Polo ........";}
                 
            return cType;
    }
    
    static String clotheSize(String size) {
        
                 if (size == "01") {cSize = " (Extra-Small) ...";}
            else if (size == "02") {cSize = " (Small) .........";}
            else if (size == "03") {cSize = " (Medium) ........";}
            else if (size == "04") {cSize = " (Large) .........";}
            else if (size == "05") {cSize = " (X-Large) .......";}
            else if (size == "06") {cSize = " (2X-Large) ......";}
            else if (size == "07") {cSize = " (3X-Large) ......";}
            else if (size == "08") {cSize = " (Add-ons) .......";}
                
            return cSize;
    }
}
```
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI04n.png)

Is there any other way to get the return values from these two methods?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi @AugustusMoran, welcome to Stack Overflow.  The reason you are getting null is because java uses `.equals()`(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) to compare strings.  You can either use say `switch (size) { case "01": ....` or change the == to .equals() to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that one of your problems is due to you using reference comparison(`==`) instead of value comparison(`.equals`).

Another one is that your regex strings are doing the opposite of what you want.

Swap the regex strings and change the `==` to `.equals()` and the functions should work right.